# Retaining existing table values using a Stored Procedure with Optional Parameter Values

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, case, optional-parameters

I have this scenario ---- where a stored procedure may be given parameter values optionally.
If the values are empty/default I would like to retain the existing values.

Is the following way of handling it with CASE statements correct? 
This works for me but is there a better way to do this?

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [UpdateUser]        
(      
 @UserID int, 
 @UserKey VARCHAR(32),     
 @UserName varchar(50),      
 @CategoryID INT = 0,  

)        
AS        
BEGIN      

 SET NOCOUNT ON      

 UPDATE [Users]      
 SET 
   [UserKey] =  (CASE WHEN (LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@UserKey)))>0) THEN @UserKey ELSE UserKey END )  
  ,[UserName] = (CASE WHEN (LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@UserName)))>0) THEN @UserName ELSE UserName END )       
  ,[CategoryID] = (CASE WHEN (@CategoryID>0) THEN @CategoryID ELSE CategoryID END )    

 WHERE         
  [UserID] = @UserID      

END
```

Comment: If there are no triggers on this table having statements that fire depending on the column(s) being updated, I think it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "better" (in terms of syntax simplicity) way to do that would be to use [`NULLIF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) and [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)/[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead of the CASE expressions:

```
UPDATE [Users]      
SET 
  UserKey    = COALESCE(NULLIF(@UserKey   , ''), UserKey   ),
  UserName   = COALESCE(NULLIF(@UserName  , ''), UserName  ),
  CategoryID = COALESCE(NULLIF(@CategoryID, 0 ), CategoryID)    
WHERE         
  UserID = @UserID
;
```

To explain the absence of `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()`, trailing spaces are ignored in string comparison in Transact-SQL. That means that a string of (any number of) spaces would match another string of (any other number of) spaces, as well as an empty string. (And, for that matter, the [`LEN()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function also ignores trailing spaces when calculating the length of a string, and so, for instance, `LEN(SPACE(10))` would return 0 and not 10.)